# А правильно ли использовать контроллер, не имеющего ни одного представления?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Возможно глупый вопрос, но я начинающий aspисатель, а также вероятнее всего ответ на него "да", но google мне не помог, потому что вопрос довольно абстрактный и одним запросом не отделаешься.

Можно ли создать специальный контроллер, у которого методы не имеют представлений, а просто выполняют такие функции как работа с куками, сессиями, и прочее. Потому что если создавать класс в Models, там нельзя будет выполнять request и response куков (например для проверки авторизованности пользователя), потому что он не связан с клиентом и работает только от контроллера. А писать в каждом контроллере метод который проверяет авторизованность, или, например, разрушает сессию, слишком неправильно, как и, опять же, использовать для этого класс в Models в который надо каждый раз передавать созданную в контроллере куку, а потом возвращать назад и выполнять остальные уникальные для каждого случая действия. Намного ведь легче использовать контроллер-посредник который выполняет всё у себя.

Может с контроллерами так давно все работают, и один я для этого использую класс в Models, где, чтобы, например, изменить значение куки, пишу в контроллере:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new CookiesManager().Change(Request.Cookies["s"]));
```

в модели CookiesManager:

```
public HttpCookie Change(HttpCookie cookie)
{
    string name=cookie.Name;
    ... //какой-то там код определяющий новое значение на основе старого
    return new HttpCookie(name,value);//value - новое значение
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Создать контроллер, у которого методы не имеют представлений, а просто выполняют некоторые функции можно. Только помните, что каждый action-метод контроллера должен вернуть [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.108).aspx)

2) Однако, для повторяющихся операций и проверок в инфраструктуре [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC предусмотрен специальный атрибут [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.108).aspx). Это абстрактный класс, который содержит методы, которые будут выполнены ДО и ПОСЛЕ действия контроллера, а также ДО и ПОСЛЕ выполнения результата действия. В собственной реализации этого атрибута вы можете использовать любое из этих действий в нужных целях.

3) Для проверки авторизации уже есть специальный атрибут - [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx).

Перечисленные выше атрибуты можно навешивать как на отдельные action-методы контроллера, так и на весь контроллер сразу.